# Where to buy 2 meter ham radio

Tags: license

I got my license 25 years ago. I bought a 2-meter ham radio from Radio Shack ($200). I am thinking about renew my license and re-start this hobby. To my surprise, local Radio Shacks no longer carry ham radios. Where do you guys buy them? What brand is good? After 25 years, the price must have come down. I am in Chicago area.

Comment: Given that you are apparently in the US, give the ARRL (or more generally, the national amateur radio association in your country) a call and ask nicely if you can have a copy of a recent membership magazine. The ads will get you started, and you may find the equipment reviews to be useful. Well-stocked libraries may also carry those membership magazines, or be able to get them for example through interlibrary loan; ask the local librarian.

Comment: Ham Radio Outlet has many stores, check their web site: http://www.hamradio.com.  Another on-line ham radio store is Universal Radio at http://universal-radio.com.  My guess is that 90 percent or better of ham radio operators in the US buy their radio equipment from on-line vendors.  The old days of walking into a retail store that specializes in ham radio is almost gone.  The multiple outlets of the chain Ham Radio Outlet is the last remaining major dealer in the US.